# How to create a new file together with missing parent directories?

Tags: java, directory, java-io, java-nio

When using

```java
file.createNewFile();
```

I get the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Parent directory of file does not exist: /.../pkg/databases/mydb
```

I am wondering is there a createNewFile that creates the missing parent directories?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
file.createNewFile();
```

I don't know of a *single* method call that will do this, but it's pretty easy as two statements.

Comment: This only works if the file was created with a path string which contains a parent directory, i.e. `new File("file.txt").getParentFile()` returns `null`, `new File("dir/file.txt").getParentFile()` returns the same as `new File("dir")`

Comment: True, you don't need `mkdirs` if the file you are trying to create is not in a non-existent directory, but my use case is that I am creating multiple files, _some_ of which have parent directories, while others do not.

Comment: If your `File` instance is itself intended to be a folder, you can simply do: `folder.mkdirs();`.

Answer (score 26):

As of java7, you can also use NIO2 API:

```
void createFile() throws IOException {
    Path fp = Paths.get("dir1/dir2/newfile.txt");
    Files.createDirectories(fp.getParent());
    Files.createFile(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Jon's answer works if you are certain that the path string with which you are creating a file includes parent directories, i.e. if you are certain that the path is of the form `<parent-dir>/<file-name>`.

If it does not, i.e. it is a relative path of the form `<file-name>`, then `getParentFile()` will return `null`.

E.g.

```
File f = new File("dir/text.txt");
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();     // works fine because the path includes a parent directory.

File f = new File("text.txt");
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();     // throws NullPointerException because the parent file is unknown, i.e. `null`.
```

So if your file path may or may not include parent directories, you are safer with the following code:

```
File f = new File(filename);
if (f.getParentFile() != null) {
  f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: for a lot of reasons you should always include a path. How else should the system know where you want to put that file ?

Comment: @NikkyD I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. In my answer, I'm not saying you're not including a path, but that the path passed may not include _parent directories_. There is also an example for such a path in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for a Kotlin solution this generally-titled question pops up.
So, for Kotlin 1.9.0 and newer there is a new [`createParentDirectories()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io.path/java.nio.file.-path/create-parent-directories.html) method on `Path` class:

```kotlin
Path("my/path/to/file.txt").createParentDirectories()
```

Comment: Do I need to `import` something or put something in my `build.gradle.kts`? I'm still a bit of a noob at Android+Kotlin stuff and I just get `Unresolved reference: createParentDirectories` in the Android Studio IDE.

Comment: @hippietrail The Kotlin version used (embedded) for Gradle scripts themselves may be different from the Kotlin version you have used/specified for your project "real" code. As of now, it seems the latest version of Gradle (8.4) is set to support Kotlin language version 1.8. So, to use this new function (introduced in Kotlin 1.9) in build scripts, should wait for new Gradle versions (and update to that) and hope its Kotlin language level is 1.9 or higher. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#kotlin

Comment: Thanks! I see I only have Gradle 8.1 in my Android Studio. After updating to 8.4, `createParentDirectories()` is still not available in my Kotlin. I actually do want to use it in my Gradle script where I'm generating a source code file. Android Studio says my Kotlin version is `223-1.9.0-release-358-AS8836.35.2231.11090377` so does that mean it should work?

Comment: @hippietrail As I said, Gradle scripts (like `build.gradle.kts` and `settings.gradle.kts`) use their own Kotlin version which may be different from the Kotlin version used for your app source code (`*.kt` files in `src/main/kotlin/` and `src/main/java/` and `src/test/kotlin/` and...). And again, as I said, Gradle **8.4** has Kotlin language version `1.8.x` which means it does not have `createParentDirectories()` in build scripts. We should wait for Gradle **8.5** and hope its Kotling language version is set to `1.9.x.`

Comment: In other words, you can change the version of Kotlin used for your app `src/...` code (confusingly, defined in your build.gradle.kts or settings.gradle.kts or libs.versions.toml  or gradle.properties) but you can NOT change the version of Kotlin for Gradle scripts themselves (AFAIK). Each Gradle version ships with its embedded Kotlin used only in Gradle scripts.