# Create a directory structure from a path in gradle/groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am implementing a diff package generation task in my project's gradle build from the git command line output. Currently I have a method which will give me a list of changed files from `git diff --name-only`. What I would like to do is create a directory structure in a new directory which matches the paths of each file. For example: inputting the string `repo/dir/file.java` would create in an output directory if not already created and inside it the directories `head/repo/dir` with the current `file.java` and `prev/repo/dir` with the previous `file.java`.

My current plan is to split the string `repo/dir/file.java` on the forward slash, and create directories until the last element of the split result, then write the file there. but nothing I have been able to come up with in gradle is nice or clean. I am wondering if there is a nicer way to create directories from a string like that.

Comment: Groovy, which runs Gradle, is executed in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Therefor, you can use the whole JDK, including the [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class. You could take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090761/how-to-create-a-new-file-together-with-missing-parent-directories), since the explained Java methods can be used. Groovy also provides [enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/overview-summary.html) for some JDK classes, including the `File` class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My current plan is to split the string `repo/dir/file.java` on the forward slash, and create directories until the last element of the split result

Rather than splitting your string manually, you could try using [`File.mkdirs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs--):

```
File newDirectoryStructureParent = new File('some/path/to/parent/dir')

def s = 'repo/dir/file.java'
def newContainer = new File(s, newDirectoryStructureParent).getParent()
newContainer.mkdirs()
```

Comment: For me, the following change was needed:

`def newContainer = new File(new File(s, newDirectoryStructureParent).getParent())`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer with a few less hoops.

```
File file = new File("full/path/to/file.java")
if(!file.getParentFile().exists()) { // Checks for "full/path/to".
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); // Creates any missing directories.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

everyone
In this part of my code you can just work around Path not File!

At the first you can define Path and second need check that path exist or not, if not mkdirs can make it ;)

Its help when you unknown about that path exist or not /

```
File fullPath = new File('/tmp/Test1')
if (!fullPath.exists())
    fullPath.mkdirs()
```

Comment: This is the same approach explain in the other answer, but it just solves half of the problem in question. It would also be good if you take some time and explain your answer instead of leaving an "everyone".

Comment: Hi BDL,
I try to add more data ;)