# Make directory using groovy

Tags: java, groovy, directory

I try to create directory using groovy.

But then i run this nothing happened.

Can't figure it out that's is wrong in this code?

```
def nametest = "try"
def patchPath = "/D/Test"
def fileName = patchPath + "/" + nametest
println fileName

if (!(new File(fileName)).exists()) {
    (new File(fileName)).mkdir()
}
```

Comment: You can follow this link, is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356577/create-a-directory-structure-from-a-path-in-gradle-groovy

Comment: @FransiskusAndikaSetiawan nope. This not helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
def nametest = 'try'
def patchPath = '/D/Test'
def fileName = "${patchPath}/${nametest}"

def file = new File(fileName)
if(!file.exists()) {
    // you can check the return value
    // of this call to know if it succeeded
    // if you like...
    file.mkdir()
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to create `/D/Test` too or is it assumed that exists?

Comment: Jeff Scott Brown - i assume this path exists

Comment: nope, not working for me

Comment: "nope, not working for me" - Very strange.  That is all standard Java API stuff.  I am sorry that I cannot help.

Comment: It may be a permission problem.  It is impossible to say for sure with what little information is provided.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/51a0ab45e926f376a77aef95d19d46ae.

Comment: thanks you already help me. You right,it's a permission issue. Don't know why groovy don't throw any error about it

Comment: "Don't know why groovy don't throw any error about it" - It is good feedback.  I think this is a case where we should honor the contract of the Java method you are invoking which includes returning `"true if and only if the directory was created; false otherwise"`.  Groovy could intercept that and turn it into an error, but I think a better idea in this case is to have `mkdir` behave the same when it is called from Groovy as when it is called from Java.

Comment: @stevemayster "Don't know why groovy don't throw any error about it" - Groovy dispatch is malleable and allows you to have that behavior if you want.  There are a number of ways to do it.  See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/stevemaystermkdir.  The comments at https://github.com/jeffbrown/stevemaystermkdir/blob/36cdc59fd8aa3c930d5643f68d0bf444a7f33ccc/app/src/main/groovy/stevemaystermkdir/App.groovy explain what is going on.  If you clone that repo and run `./gradlew run` you will see the exception thrown.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/cc41714a4df0ea0f0692866d696fd5a4